# reCAPTCHA MAILCHIMP suscriptores

Tags: php, html, email

Tengo mis formularios creados con **mailchimp** para las webs de mis clientes. El problema es que estos últimos días han empezado a recibir peticiones de suscriptores falsos o robots.

Sé que en **mailchimp** hay una opción de hacer que estos robots no puedan rellenar el formulario con un **reCAPTCHA**, pero no sé cómo implementarlo en la web. Podríais decirme como hacer para crear un **recaptcha** para introducirlo en una web ya creada? .

Por favor describírmelo con todo lujo de detalles si puede ser.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes encontrar la opción dentro de `Signup Forms > Embedded forms > Form options > Protect your form`. [Mas info aquí](http://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/signup-forms/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website#Embedded-Form-Options)

Comment: Entonces hay una opción en el mailchimp de activar reCAPTCHA y cuando activo esa opción ya se añade automaticamente a los formularios sin necesidad de añadir nada de codigo a la web?????

Comment: Hasta donde se (_la verdad no estoy seguro_), debes añadir nuevamente el código del formulario en la web

Comment: Gracias Marcos Gallardo, pero me ayudaría que alguien que lo haya hecho recientemente me diga cómo lo ha hecho, para intentarlo de forma similar a ver si da resultado.

Answer (score 0):

Un modo de hacerlo es siguiendo las instrucciones del mismo programa...

[image: Modo de incluir un reCaptcha en Mailchimp]

([Fuente](http://kb.mailchimp.com/es/lists/signup-forms/add-a-signup-form-to-your-website))